# PHP Classes With Multiple Children Sharing Same Parent Instance

Tags: php, class

I'm having trouble getting my head around the best way to perfect my system. Currently, it's pretty archaic, so I'm interested to know if you have any suggestions about improving it?

User Class -> handles data and basic functions on users that are referenced on the page. The __construct takes an ID and uses the get_user() function to get the user's data with the given ID.
UserService (extends User) -> handles login, logout, etc. Is called at the top of every file to figure out if a user is logged in, and is defined as $user = new UserService(); every pageload, which presents the current user's data from User  class.
UserNotifications (extends user) -> handles user notifications.

The problem that I'm having is that I have various child classes, such as the ones above, that interact with each other and I don't want them each calling an instance of the parent that may already be instantiated through another child.

Obviously that adds unnecessary queries. What's the best way to pass parent instances between child classes?

At this point, I'm a novice to OOP, and I've been stumped by this. I also apologise for the lack of clarity. I hope that you understand.

Comment: Perhaps by using composition rather than inheritance.... rather than having all these child classes extending a common parent; change your parent to a new class, instantiate that once, then pass it to all your other classes in their constructor when they are instantiated, saving it s a property, so that single instance is available to all instances

Comment: But where you have inheritance, you don't instantiate the parent class as well as the children, you instantiate the child, and that then inherits the properties/methods of the parent class

Comment: What do you understand as `children` and `parent` classes: inheritance relations or when one object calls another one or owns something.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply clone for this purpose, so posting an answer with an example may be best for that one.

Composition is one way that I've thought. So, basically, with some adjustment to the old 'child' classes, instantiate them like this: $user_notification = new UserNotification($instantiated_user_class) and apply it to a property, right?

Comment: Also, @MichałSznurawa, I understand that when children are instantiated, they also create a new instance of the parent. Each of the child classes use 'extends' to the parent. However, new instances of the parent, especially when child classes are interacting with each other or with a previously declared parent, isn't efficient because the parent isn't static and the __construct takes the user's ID and performs a query to get that user. Is there a more efficient way? Perhaps composition is the best way t ogo?

Comment: Best what you can do is to try to follow @MarkBaker suggestions.

Comment: It looks like your classes structure is breaking S and L principles from SOLID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: `I understand that when children are instantiated, they also create a new instance of the parent.` This is where your undesrtanding on inheritance is incorrect.... When you instantiate a child class, no instance of the parent is created, only an instance of the child class that contains the methods and properties of the parent as well as of the child.

Comment: @MarkBaker, correct. What I meant to say was that the __construct is called once more and anything that's not static is a blank slate. All data from previous calls is lost.

Comment: Well you shouldn't ever be calling `__construct()` manually.... but when you use `new myClass()` then you are creating a new instance of the class, totally independent and distinctive from any other instances of that class

Comment: @MarkBaker, I'm not calling the __construct manually, but what I'm saying is that the parent's __construct is called if the child does not have a construct and the child is instantiated. I think this is offtopic to the point now, but I do agree with what you said about composite inheritance.

Comment: Did you ever get past this problem? Contrary to the commenters I know exactly what you mean. You want child-classes to be able to communicate with eachother, but calling one will re-instantiate the parent class, meaning the old variables (probably including another child class) are lost. Automatically including them won't work as it'd turn into an infinite loop.